# Trying to connect a Korean IPS (2560x1440) to a Macbook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012, 1.8 GHz Intel Core i5)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I'm trying to get a Macbook Air to work with a Korean IPS. It's not a big deal -- I have it set up on my Linux machine, but I'd like to be able to watch some videos (Amazon Prime HD) that don't work on Linux.

I have a Mini DisplayPort <--> DVI connector, and a dual-link DVI cable. The cable works with my Linux desktop (which has a GeForce — [setup notes](http://blog.gatoatigrado.com/2012/08/configuring-crossover-27q-led-p-on.html)). When I plug the Mini DisplayPort into the Macbook Air, I get the following in `/var/log/system.log`,

```
May 17 21:13:45 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Received display connect changed for display 0x42737c0
May 17 21:13:45 gatoatigrado-air kernel[0]: EDID CEA Extensions not valid for audio (minimum value: 2) [Extension Tag]: -1
May 17 21:13:45 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Created shield window 0x6ed for display 0x042737c0
May 17 21:13:45 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: no action for lock state 1
May 17 21:13:45 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
May 17 21:13:45 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: _MPCompleteConnectChange: Fatal error remapping framebuffer
May 17 21:13:45 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Display 0x042737c0: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 12 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model 9cdf, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0x0000061000009cdf00000000042737c0, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x00000007, accelerator 0x00003e93, unit 0, caps QEX|QGL|MIPMAP, vram 1156 MB
    texture units 8, texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003e
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003d
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Created shield window 0x6ee for display 0x042737c0
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Created shield window 0x6ef for display 0x003f003e
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Created shield window 0x6f0 for display 0x003f003d
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Display 0x042737c0: MappedDisplay Unit 0: Startup Mode 1440 x 900, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, IOMode 0x80000000, IODepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Display added
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Display removed
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Display 0x042737c0: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 12 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model 9cdf, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0x0000061000009cdf00000000042737c0, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x00000007, accelerator 0x00003e93, unit 0, caps QEX|QGL|MIPMAP, vram 1156 MB
    texture units 8, texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003e
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003d
May 17 21:13:46 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x042737c0 device: 0x103ade110  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
May 17 21:13:47 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
May 17 21:13:47 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Display 0x042737c0: MappedDisplay Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 3)
May 17 21:13:48 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
May 17 21:13:48 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
May 17 21:13:48 gatoatigrado-air.local WindowServer[91]: Display 0x042737c0: MappedDisplay Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 3)
May 17 21:14:18 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
```

In particular, the `Fatal error remapping framebuffer` sounds like it's something that could be fixed with different configuration .... Unfortunately, the Apple System tools are unhelpful; the displays settings shows nothing; the System Information thunderbolt section says nothing is connected.